# Can you clarify How to use the word "technically" that has the meaning of "strictly speaking"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I heard a lot of native English speakers use the word "`technically`" that has the meaning of "`strictly speaking`".

Search on internet, "`technically`" means "`according to the facts or exact meaning of something`" https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Atechnically

**So what does "`according to the facts or exact meaning of something`" mean? can you clarify it?**

Comment: It is really more about the fact that people tend to speak imprecisely and in generalities most of the time. The word "technically" is just shorthand for "what follows is meant to be taken a little more strictly than usual" and that it may point to a domain of knowledge that could be revealed in subsequent conversation. If your mom tells you "Eat your vegetables," you might well counter "Technically, a tomato is a fruit." But for the purposes of the meal your mom prepared, you would probably not be surprised to find that you were unlikely to win that argument.

Comment: Technical : Used in or peculiar to a specific field or profession; specialized: technical jargon. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/technically

Comment: Are you asking what 'technically' means , technically?